# Deferred Deeplink not working on iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, deep-linking, deferred

Hi im having a issue with deferred deeplinks on iOS 10. Its strange because it only happen on iOS 10 and above. On iOS 9 and 8 it works fine.
When I send deferred deeplink from  APP ADS Helper the result which i get in the below metod in iOS 10 is  “success” instead of the url which i need to handle, which is recived fine on iOS 8 and 9.

```
[deferredAppLinkRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                                      id result,
                                                      NSError *error)];
```

In the documentation it says :  ” Beginning with iOS 10, iOS doesn’t support deferred deep linking, so you can’t open content other than the starting screen once people have installed the app. ”

What should i do ? does ios 10 not support deferred deeplinks anymore, should i handle it linke normal deeplink in
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation  ?

Here is my code in didFinishLaunching

```
if (launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey] == nil) {
      [FBSDKAppLinkUtility fetchDeferredAppLink:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
           NSLog(@“LINK %@  ERRROR %@“,url, error);

           if (error) {
               NSLog(@“Received error while fetching deferred app link %@“, error);
           }
           if (url) {
           // IM HANDLING IT HERE
               if ([[url host] isEqualToString:@“deeplink”]) {
                  if ([[url path] isEqualToString:@“/smth”]) {
                    //my code }
                }
           }
```

previously worked fine with this code, suddenly stoped working on iOS 10 and i dont have Url to handle ?
Any ideas ?

Comment: May be this can help you: https://blog.branch.io/ios-10-wwdc-deep-linking-review/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Beginning with iOS 10, iOS doesn’t support deferred deep linking, so you can’t open content other than the starting screen once people have installed the app

This might be true, **if you're relying on Facebook for deferred deep link handling.** This was never a good idea, because Facebook's deferred deep link functionality is not good (to put it mildly).

Fortunately there other options for this. I'd recommend looking at the [Facebook ads functionality](https://dev.branch.io/features/facebook-ads/overview/) from [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team).